# Is the Azure Table Client for .NET Threadsafe?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

Can I just have one global instance of the client and table, or do I need a separate instance per thread?

reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Each individual class should describe whether it is thread-safe or not. I know some are. I suspect some are not.

Example: [CloudTable's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.cloudtable.aspx) public static methods are thread-safe but instances of the class are not.

More than likely, you'll want multiple instances of these. If you have some strange scaling issue where this is problematic, consider creating a "ClientPool" somewhat akin to a Connection Pool to lease and reuse instances.

Comment: That's the boiler-plate text they put on every thing. It could be true, or it could be someone was being lazy.

Comment: If it is pooling internally, then creating my own connection pool would be counter-productive.

Comment: That's the boiler-plate text they put on everything that isn't thread-safe. If they put extra effort into making something thread-safe, the documentation tends to reliably reflect that. I'm sure there has been an exception to that but even if that's the case, unless they claim it's thread-safe then a future service pack or otherwise could change that behavior on you even in those cases.

Comment: Another threading issue is links between classes. TableClient doesn't hold a reference to StorageAccount, so StorageAccount can be protected by a simple sync-lock. But Table holds a reference to TableClient.